# How can I split a URL into three different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I want to split a URL into three strings.
Example:

```
https://www.google.com:443
http://amazon.com:467
```

I would like the output to be:

```
string 1: https or http
string 2: www.google.com or amazon.com
string 3: 443 or 467
```

The above output is based on the example provided. Basically I want to split the string into `protocol`, `domain` and `port` and assign to three different variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ULRs are more complicated than one might think which is why it's generally a good idea to use proven code to parse them and handle unexpected edge cases. Python has [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse) in the library, which you should use rather than trying to parse this your self.

The parts you want are in the `scheme`, `hostname`, and `port` properties of the object returned from `urlsparse()`

For example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def getParts(url_string):
    p = urlparse(url_string)
    return [p.scheme, p.hostname, p.port]

getParts('https://www.google.com:443')
# ['https', 'www.google.com', 443]

getParts('http://amazon.com:467')
# ['http', 'amazon.com', 467]

# surprising, but valid url:
getParts('https://en.wikipedia.org:443/wiki/Template:Welcome')
# ['https', 'en.wikipedia.org', 443]

# missing parts:
getParts('//www.google.com/example/home')
# ['', 'www.google.com', None]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Meyer. Perfect solution for my problem statement.

Comment: Mark Meyer, i have a situation were the URL seems to be https://domainname/add/input. were i would like to capture the whole p.hostname domainname/add/input. Appreciate your thoughts in this.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com:443'

first = url.find(':')
last = url.rfind(':')

protocol = url[:first]
domain = url[first+3:last]
port = url[last+1:]
```

Comment: This works for these, but urls can have `:` in other parts so as a general solution, this is fragile.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I've accounted for that and it should be good now. I've also put in that missing `:` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A 'primitive' method:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def split_url(url):
    split_1 = url.split('://')
    split_2 = split_1[1].split(':')
    protocol = split_1[0]
    domain = split_2[0]
    port = split_2[1]

    url_split = namedtuple('url_split', ['protocol', 'domain', 'port'])
    return url_split(protocol, domain, port)
```

So, for example:

```
s = 'https://www.google.com:443'
result = split_url(s)
```

Then we have:

```
result.protocol
>> 'https'

result.domain
>> 'www.google.com'

result.port
>> '443'
```